# Is it possible to avoid writing this block calling code 'backwards'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I have an asynchronous method in Objective C to which you pass a completion handler.

I wish to **conditionally** run this method twice, on two different objects, then process the results.

The only way in which I can find to make this work is to write the code 'backwards', as per below.

This implies a major architectural failing on my part.  Is there a better way?

*defines.h*

```
    #define BLOCK_SAFE_RUN(block, ...) block ? block(__VA_ARGS__) : nil
```

*myController.h*

```
    // Code executes in the order (0),(1),(2),(3),(4) - see comments


    // (0) Create the origin completion handler
    void (^originCompletionHandler)(FAPlacePoint *, BOOL, BOOL) = ^void (FAPlacePoint *savedOriginPP, BOOL geoCodeDidSucceed, BOOL saveDidSucceed)
    {

        // (2) Create the destination completion handler
        void (^destinationCompletionHandler)(FAPlacePoint *, BOOL, BOOL) = ^void (FAPlacePoint *savedDestinationPP, BOOL geoCodeDidSucceed, BOOL saveDidSucceed)
        {

            // (4)
            // Everything is finished.  Do something with savedOriginPP and savedDestinationPP


        };

        // (3) Conditionally run the geocode method with the dest point then call the destination completion handler
        if (destinationPlacePoint.currentLocation)
            [self reverseGeocodeThenSavePlacePoint:destinationPlacePoint completion:destinationCompletionHandler];
        else
        {
            FAPlacePoint * pp = [self storePlacePoint:destinationPlacePoint];
            BLOCK_SAFE_RUN(destinationCompletionHandler, pp, YES, YES);
        }


    };


    // (1) Conditionally run the geocode method with the origin point then call the origin completion handler
    if (originPlacePoint.currentLocation)
        [self reverseGeocodeThenSavePlacePoint:originPlacePoint completion:originCompletionHandler];
    else
    {
        FAPlacePoint * pp = [self storePlacePoint:originPlacePoint];
        BLOCK_SAFE_RUN(originCompletionHandler, pp, YES, YES);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got duplicated code, so that should be separated out into a method:

```
- (void) processPoint:(FAPlacePoint*)point completionHandler:(void (^)(FAPlacePoint *savedPP, BOOL geoCodeDidSucceed, BOOL saveDidSucceed))completionHandler
{
    if (point.currentLocation)
        [self reverseGeocodeThenSavePlacePoint:point completion:completionHandler];
    else
    {
        FAPlacePoint * pp = [self storePlacePoint:point];
        BLOCK_SAFE_RUN(completionHandler, pp, YES, YES);
    }
}
```

That allows you to avoid storing the blocks in variables just to avoid duplicating them. So, your code reduces down to:

```
[self processPoint:originPlacePoint completionHandler:^void (FAPlacePoint *savedOriginPP, BOOL geoCodeDidSucceed, BOOL saveDidSucceed) {
    [self processPoint:destinationPlacePoint completionHandler:^void (FAPlacePoint *savedDestinationPP, BOOL geoCodeDidSucceed, BOOL saveDidSucceed) {

        // Everything is finished.  Do something with savedOriginPP and savedDestinationPP

    }];
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

> This implies a major architectural failing on my part. Is there a better way?

No it doesn't. Maybe you just need to adjust your point of view.

You can't use a variable to invoke a block until you've defined it, so the code for something like a completion handler will always precede the code that calls it. There's nothing wrong with that. It's like telling someone your plan before executing it: *After leaving the office, I'll stop at the grocery store.* Computer languages don't usually have an actual future tense, but it might help to think of defining blocks before calling them as writing code in the future tense.

If it *really* bothers you to have the completion code before the code that causes it to run, you can sometimes put that code in its own method, so that the completion block itself consists of little more than a call to that method. That method can, of course, follow the code that calls it (but the completion block itself still needs to be defined before you use it).

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea that you have to define a block before using it. Any method that takes a block parameter can have the block defined inline with the call. So to run a series of blocks in order they would just be nested.

Comment: @jshier To be more precise, you have to define a block *variable* before you can use it to invoke the block. Of course you can use the block itself as a parameter, but you'll notice that the OP wants to invoke the same block from two different places. Ken Thomases' answer helps avoid the need for that in this particular case. In general, though, if you're going to use the same block in more than one place, you need to assign it to a variable, and you obviously need to do that before you invoke the block using that variable.

Comment: I very much appreciated your answer.  The only reason I gave the answer to Ken Thomases is that, strictly speaking, he provided code that solved the stated problem.

Comment: @CarlosP Thanks, and no worries -- Ken's answer is a good one too. Glad you found both answers helpful.